# Get prices of all Cryptocurrencies

Tags: python

I I am trying to make a Crypto Barometer. I have a little piece of code that gets the price in USD for each symbol. Now I want to add them up and get the total of these coins (the prices of one of each coin). I got the realtime prices, but I don't know how to add them up. I also want the price of each symbol one, four, eight and 24 hours ago...

```
In the end it should look like this  :
Current             1Hour                ...  24Hours
BTCUSDT $49343.34   BTCUSDT $49133.12         BTCUSDT $48763.34
...                 ...                       ..
ETHUSDT $2123.84    ETHUSDT $2087.53          ETHUSDT $1987.23
sum : $6255422.23   Sum : $6249983m92         Sum : 6187291.51
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
import json
import datetime
import time

api_request = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price')
api = json.loads(api_request.content)

for x in api:
    print(x['symbol'], "${0:.4f}".format(float(x['price'])))

# THE PART WHERE I GOT DIFFERENT TIMES
while True:
    dt = datetime
    cur_time = (dt.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m %H:%M'))
    one_hour = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%d-%m %H:%M')
    four_hours = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=4)).strftime('%d-%m %H:%M')
    eight_hours = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=8)).strftime('%d-%m %H:%M')
    one_day = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=24)).strftime('%d-%m %H:%M')

    print(cur_time)
    print(one_hour)
    print(four_hours)
    print(eight_hours)
    print(one_day)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Why don't you read Binance API docs?

Comment: I did... I got the answer for getting the prices, but not how to sum them up...

Answer (score 0):

there is a [API library](https://github.com/lagerfeuer/cryptocompare) to get prices of nearly every crypto

```
import cryptocompare

def crypto_price('BTC'):
    coin_acronym = str(acronyms['BTC'])
    price_crypto = cryptocompare.get_price(coin_acronym, currency='USD', full=True).get('RAW').get(coin_acronym).get(
        'USD').get(
        'PRICE')
    return price_crypto
```

Comment: Thanks. But the getting the prices part is not the problem. The summing up AND retreving precise historical data is...